# How do I tile a texture to soften out the joins?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

The gold texture and the scratch texture I am using on this gold bar are creating obvious lines where the edge of the texture is. Is there a way of graduating or feathering them so the joins are not so noticeable, simply by using texture nodes? I know I have seen it done on a number of tutorials but I cannot seem to locate them.[image]

Comment: In a photo editing application like Photoshop or maybe Gimp (Free) you need to mirror a portion of one of the sides of the texture image to the other and then mirror a portion of the top or bottom. Hope that makes sense. Because the lighting is uneven it will be difficult but not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 3D view, you can switch to *Texture Paint*, choose the *Clone* brush:

[image]

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click on the part that you want to sample, and paint on the seams that you want to dissolve:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!